# Issue with the "open with" option Miui13/Android12

Tags: android-12, miui-13

I have an issue with my smartphone, the "open with" option doesn't work properly, so when I click on a link (from gmail for example or to open a file) normally I am given the choice to choose on which application I want to open it, but since the last update (miui 12.5 to 13 / android 11 to 12) I can't choose , when I click on "plus" or "more" in the "open with" window to have the choices it doesn't show any suggestions and select randomly an application (sometimes chrome, other times tor/edge/mi browser ... etc).

- device : xiaomi poco f2 pro
- miui version : 13.0.2 stable
- Android version : 12 SKQ 1.211006.001

Issue in the android framework(I think): `com.android.internal.app.MiuiResolverActivity`

What should I do? Please help me up.

Comment: I cannot add an answer but I have just resolved this by disabling mi browser (see which Mi native apps are being opened and disable those)

Comment: and how to disable mi browser please?

Comment: @Simona the question has been unprotected, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to Settings> Default Applications and see what your default Browser app is set to.

Then clear the "open with default" options under that respective app's "app info" section

Comment: no, that's not the problem, I don't have a default browser, I always prefer to select the app I want to use myself, but when I want to see the suggestions (When I press see more) for choosing an app It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a Mi11 gadget. I removed some apps (MiBrowser that I never intended to use + Samsung printer driver + Samsung printer app) and it went OK again. Do you want to give it a try? Please share your experiences too :)

Comment: And how to remove a system application please?

Comment: It just let me remove them as normal applications... Do you have any different experience?

Comment: Yes, when I long press it, uninstall/remove doesn't show up in suggestions like other apps show.